# xrdp on Ubuntu 18.04 launches terminal windows on local Desktop

Tags: command-line, 18.04, remote-desktop, environment-variables

While installing ubuntu 18.04 and Xrdp I mush have messed up something and now I get the following behavior:

When I logon from either the local desktop or a remote session everything is fine, if however I logon to Desktop and then open a remote session from another machine the following happens:

when I open a terminal window from either session the terminal opens on the local desktop, and when I open a UI application is opens on the remote session, no matter from where I do it.

I appreciate any tips on how to fix this ...

Thank you